# Can't get array of sorted items to show results on screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

In [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AQFFq/21/), I'm trying to sort the items from high to low price by calling the following function:

```
function myFunction() {
  var elements = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("price"));
  elements.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(b.innerHTML.substring(1)) - parseFloat(a.innerHTML.substring(1));
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    elements[i].parentNode.appendChild(elements[i]);
  console.log(elements);
}
```

I can see it working when I console.log, but I can't get the results to actually appear on the screen and change the order of my items.

I see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AQFFq/2/) with the below JavaScript, it works, why doesn't mine?

```
 $(function() {
    $(".offer_item").sort(function(a, b) {
        var priceAText = $(a).find(".offer_price").text();
        var priceBText = $(b).find(".offer_price").text();
        var priceA = parseFloat(priceAText.substring(1, priceAText.length));
        var priceB = parseFloat(priceBText.substring(1, priceBText.length));
        return priceA > priceB;
    }).each(function() {
      $(this).appendTo(".offer_list");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The working example sorts items in the document.

Your code creates an array `elements` **outside of the document** with references to elements in de document. You then sort this array, which does not change your document at all.

When you execute `elements[i].parentNode.appendChild(elements[i]);`, `element[i]` is still the reference to an element in the document and `.parentNode` is in the document too, so there you do edit the document.